# How to find the splitting field for $x^3-x^2-x-2$ over $\Bbb Q$?

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, splitting-field

I'm not quite sure on how to solve this one. Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*: This polynomial has a rational root. Actually, it factors as 
$$x^3-x^2-x-2=(x-2)(x^2+x+1),$$
so it  is the splitting field of the quadratic polynomial $x^2+x+1$, which I'm sure you've already met.